# JOOQ Maven plugin NullPointerException

Tags: maven, jooq

How can I resolve the NullPointerException I'm getting with the jooq-maven-plugin 3.7.3, Maven 3.3.9, Java 1.8.0_51, and OS X 10.10.4?

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.7.3:generate (default-cli) on project my-app: Error running jOOQ code generation tool: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.7.3:generate (default-cli) on project my-app: Error running jOOQ code generation tool
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error running jOOQ code generation tool
>       at org.jooq.util.maven.Plugin.execute(Plugin.java:134)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
>       ... 20 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.jooq.util.maven.Plugin.execute(Plugin.java:118)
>       ... 22 more

According to the code [on Github](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ-codegen-maven/src/main/java/org/jooq/util/maven/Plugin.java) the line throwing the NPE is

```
String dir = generator.getTarget().getDirectory();
```

My target directory configured below does indeed exist and I have tried both relative and absolute paths as well as not using a property to set it.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>my-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <db>myappdb</db>
    <db.driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</db.driver>
    <db.jdbc>jdbc:mysql://localhost</db.jdbc>
    <db.url>${db.jdbc}/${db}</db.url>
    <db.user>root</db.user>
    <db.pass>rootpass</db.pass>

    <jaxb-api.version>2.2.6</jaxb-api.version>
    <jooq.version>3.7.3</jooq.version>
    <jooq.dialect>org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDatabase</jooq.dialect>
    <jooq.gen.directory>target</jooq.gen.directory>
    <jooq.gen.package>com.mycompany.app.jooq</jooq.gen.package>
    <junit.version>3.8.1</junit.version>
    <mysql.driver.version>5.1.38</mysql.driver.version>
  </properties>

  <build>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
          <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
          <version>${jooq.version}</version>
          <executions>

            <execution>
              <id>jooq-generate</id>
              <phase>generate-sources</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <jdbc>
                  <driver>${db.driver}</driver>
                  <url>${db.url}</url>
                  <user>${db.user}</user>
                  <password>${db.pass}</password>
                </jdbc>
               <generator>
                 <database>
                   <name>${jooq.dialect}</name>
                     <includes>.*</includes>
                     <excludes> UNUSED_TABLE
                        | PREFIX_.*
                        | SECRET_SCHEMA\.SECRET_TABLE # This table (qualified name) should not be generated
                        | SECRET_ROUTINE # This routine (unqualified name) ...
                     </excludes>
                     <inputSchema>${db}</inputSchema>
                     <!--outputSchema /-->
                     <!--dateAsTimestamp>true</dateAsTimestamp -->
                 </database>
                 <generate>
                    <relations>true</relations>
                    <deprecated>true</deprecated>
                    <instanceFields>true</instanceFields>
                    <generatedAnnotation>true</generatedAnnotation>
                    <records>true</records>
                    <pojos>true</pojos>
                    <immutablePojos>true</immutablePojos>
                    <interfaces>true</interfaces>
                    <daos>true</daos>
                    <jpaAnnotations>true</jpaAnnotations>
                    <validationAnnotations>true</validationAnnotations>
                    <springAnnotations>true</springAnnotations>
                    <globalObjectReferences>true</globalObjectReferences>
                    <fluentSetters>false</fluentSetters>
                 </generate>
                 <target>
                    <packageName>${jooq.gen.package}</packageName>
                    <directory>${jooq.gen.directory}</directory>
                 </target>
              </generator>
            </configuration>
          </execution>

        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb-api.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
    <version>${jooq.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
    <version>${jooq.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
    <version>${jooq.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>${mysql.driver.version}</version>
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Huh, the only thing that I can see missing is the `<phase>generate-sources</phase>`. It would be surprising if that caused any issue, though... Is that it?

Comment: @LukasEder No doubt, you never know.  I added it and am getting the same results though.

Comment: Have you `mvnDebug`-ed through it already? Is the `Plugin.generator` property `null`? Or also the `jdbc` property?

Comment: @LukasEder haven't debugged it yet. I used the command line to work around this to fill my immediate need, but that won't scale as well as I'ld like so I'll have to dig into this problem more if no one has the answer.

Comment: Hmm, I suspect this is really a very rare edge case. We would have had the bug report much earlier if it was an obvious issue. Have you had a chance to debug through this?

Comment: @LukasEder Thanks for checking in.  I wouldn't be surprised if I've done something stupid in the pom.  Haven't debugged yet as I'm evaluating other code generators as well.

Comment: I've encountered a similar issue. The issue was that I was running `mvn org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:generate` next to the root pom.xml but my jooq plugin configuration was in a sub module. Running in the right sub folder fixed the issue. It seems that the jooq codegen plugin results in a NullPointerException if no configuration is present.

Comment: @GuiSim thanks, I had a similar issue. Running in the right folder fixed it for me.